# Rails - how to count data loaded from ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, activerecord, count

I am loading data like this:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:car_services, :services).where(...)
```

And when I need to get only unique data from there, I do it this way:

```
<% @cars.uniq_by {|x| x["brand"]}.each do |car| %>
  <%= I'd need to print out here the count of cars for 'car.brand' from '@cars' %>
```

How can I do that? I was thinking about doing something like this:

```
@cars = Car.includes(:car_services, :services).where(...)
@cars2 = @cars
```

and then in the cycle to use `car.brand` and search in `@cars2`, but that wouldn't be probably very effective... What would be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Can you elaborate this: "and then in the cycle to use car.brand and search in @cars2,"

Answer (score 2):

You can use: `Hash[@cars.group_by(&:brand).map {|k,v| [k,v.length]}]`

It will return a `hash` consisting of all the brands with their respective count

You can then do something like this then:

```
<% arr = Hash[@cars.group_by(&:brand).map {|k,v| [k,v.length]}] %>
<% @cars.uniq_by {|x| x["brand"]}.each do |car| %>
    <%= arr["#{car.brand}"] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, it's working. I'd need yet to similarly save also IDs of those records (cars IDs), so the string would look like this: `1,2,5,10`. How to do this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting your question correctly this should work:

```
   <% @cars.pluck(:brand).uniq.each do |brand|%>
      <%= @cars.where(brand: brand).count %>
    <% end%>
```

Though, I would prefer moving this logic to Car model instead of having it in views

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you right, but this should do the trick:

```
@cars.group(:brand).count
```

Does everything via SQL and returns a hash with the brand as key and count as value:

```
# => { 'Audi' => 123, 'BMW' => 321, ... }
```